# Convert all cell values in a row to string using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following row in a csv file and I want to concatenate all cell values in single row and convert them to a string.

Input:

```
      A      B    C    D    E  
A   hello  Alan  How  are  you
```

Output: hello Alan How are you

Here is what i have now:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
output = [''.join(str(df.values[:,i])) for i in range(len(df.values))]
```

Exception:

```
IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 8
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If need processing only one row seelct it by position with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and add `join`:

```
output = ' '.join(df.iloc[0])
```

```
output = ' '.join(df.loc['A'])

print (output)
hello Alan How are you
```

For processing all rows:

```
s = df.apply(' '.join, 1)
```

Comment: thanks for upvoting the answer, appreciate your support +1 as always.  I see , many of peoples here are silent killers :-)

Comment: @ jezrael,  same experience, in one of my answer someone downvoted and when i asked he removed the downvote, seems very crazy behaviour SO must have some catch there if someone downvotes  his profile should be visible so that we can ask the downvoter directly and if he/she do not justify the downvote just ban the guy!

Comment: @KarnKumar - Yes, I think about this a lot and only ways is starts from me - always if dive downvote clearly explain why. and if answer is changed, always remove downvote.

Comment: @KarnKumar - btw, if you feels sometins downvote was wrong, give me comment for any my answer with link for downvoted answer and I can upvote it ;)

Comment: thanks for the encouraging comments thats helps to move :-)

Comment: @KarnKumar - ya, there has to be clear for answerer, if something wrong (because sometimen downvoter only think, it is wrong, but answer is perfect ;))

Answer (score 0):

You could try..

```
df
       A     B    C    D    E
A  hello  Alan  How  are  you
```

Result:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
A    hello Alan How are you
dtype: object
```